# How to plot .tif file colour coding onto the map using javascript?

Tags: javascript, plot, tiff, react-leaflet

I want to plot colour coding from `.tif` file into the map with the help of react-leaflet. How can this be done?
I am open for other better suggestions. My core goal is to display color coding given in geotiff file on an interactive map dynamically on a website.